# C - allocating values in an array of pointers in outside function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, function-call

Lets say I have the following situation (some rough pseudocode):

```
struct { 
  int i;
} x

main(){
  x** array = malloc(size of x pointer); // pointer to an array of pointers of type x
  int* size = current size of x // (initally 0)
  add(array, size);
}

add(x** array, int* size){ // adds one actual element to the array
  x** temp = realloc(array, (*size)+1); // increase the array size by one
  free(array);
  array = temp;

  // My question is targeted here
  array[*size] = malloc(size of x); // makes a pointer to the value 
  array[*size]->i = size;
  *size++;  
}
```

My question is: Once add() is finished, do the values of the pointers stored in array disappear along with the function call stack, since I allocated them inside func()? I fear that they might, in which case would there be a better way for me to do things?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to free memory after you realloc'ed it..

Comment: @Ancurio be a *little* more sure of yourself, because you're entirely correct. At least he realloced to a temporary rather than blinding-over his array and potentially leaking it if the realloc fails. He didn't check this, but it is pseudo code, and its half there, so at least thats something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't. They persist until the pointer returned by `malloc()` is passed to the corresponding `free()` function. There would be no point in the existence of the `malloc()` function if it worked the same way as automatic arrays.

Edit: sidenote. As @Ancurio pointer it out, you're incorrectly freeing the memory behind the previous pointer returned by `malloc()` which is at that time invalid as `realloc()` has been used on it. Don't do that. `realloc()` does its job properly.)

Comment: +1: I'm not too all that clear on what is going on with passing a pointer set to a scalar constant is for either (`int *size = size of x`), but I've seen stranger things. I think he meant `int size` and then pass it by `&size`